# How to display one bibliography in different styles according to the language which is used in the references using CSL and citeproc?

Tags: pandoc, bibtex, bibliography, citations, csl

I would like to ask a question related to [an ongoing issue](https://github.com/jgm/citeproc/issues/120) in the GitHub repository of [jgm/citeproc](https://github.com/jgm/citeproc) here, since my question may come to be out of scope of the original issue.

I'm trying to apply an approach proposed in [a comment](https://github.com/jgm/citeproc/issues/120#issuecomment-1296189432) on the thread on GitHub to [a `csl` file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pulipulichen/blogger/master/project/zotero/apa_zh_pulipuli.csl) so that I can display English references and non-English ones (Chinese `lang-zh`, here) in different layouts according to their language. That is, when [citeproc](https://github.com/jgm/citeproc) finds that a bib entry of a `.bib` file contains a csl's `variable` (say `lang-zh`), that bib entry is displayed in a layout that is specified in the csl's if-statement as shown below:

```xml
<citation>
   ...
    <layout>
      <choose>
        <if variable="lang-zh">
          <!--
             Multibyte comma as a deliminater for non-English references
          -->
          <group delimiter="，">
            <text macro="author-short-zh" />
            <text macro="issued-year-zh" />
            <text macro="citation-locator-zh" />
          </group>
        </if>
        <else>
          <!--
             Normal comma as a deliminater for references in the default language (English)
          -->
          <group delimiter=", ">
            <text macro="author-short" />
            <text macro="issued-year" />
            <text macro="citation-locator" />
          </group>
        </else>
      </choose>
    </layout>
  </citation>
```

However, the variable/tag `lang-zh` in the `.bib` file seems to be ignored even when I add such filed as `lang-zh  = {yes}`, `variable = {lang-zh}`, or `language = {lang-zh}` to the `.bib` file, as shown below.

```
@article{chen2012,
  title    = {基于电无级变速器的内燃机最优控制策略及整车能量管理},
  author   = {陈骁 and 黄声华 and 万山明 and 庞珽},
  journal  = {电工技术学报},
  volume   = {27},
  number   = {2},
  pages    = {133--138},
  year     = {2012},
  lang-zh  = {yes},
  variable = {lang-zh},
  language = {lang-zh}
}
```

Then how should I add a filed or variable to the `.bib` file that can be recognised by the csl?

[image]

## (M)WE

### Full `.csl` file (say `mod_apa_zh_pulipuli.csl`)

You can find the `.csl` file from https://github.com/jgm/citeproc/issues/120#issuecomment-1296207148

(Its original csl called `apa_zh_pulipuli.csl` is from  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pulipulichen/blogger/master/project/zotero/apa_zh_pulipuli.csl)

### `tests.bib`

```
@book{xie2015,
  title     = {Dynamic Documents with {R} and knitr},
  author    = {Yihui Xie},
  publisher = {Chapman and Hall/CRC},
  address   = {Boca Raton, Florida},
  year      = {2015},
  edition   = {2nd},
  note      = {ISBN 978-1498716963},
  url       = {http://yihui.name/knitr/},
  language  = {English}
}
@article{chen2012,
  title    = {基于电无级变速器的内燃机最优控制策略及整车能量管理},
  author   = {陈骁 and 黄声华 and 万山明 and 庞珽},
  journal  = {电工技术学报},
  volume   = {27},
  number   = {2},
  pages    = {133--138},
  year     = {2012},
  lang-zh  = {yes},
  variable = {lang-zh},
  language = {lang-zh}
}
```

### `test.md`

```
---
bibliography: [test.bib]
csl: mod_apa_zh_pulipuli.csl
---

@xie2015

@chen2012
```

Comment: As per the answers in that github issue, I'm fairly certain you won't get this to work with bibtex (or even biblatex). Have you tried with CSL JSON? Is that an option?

Comment: @adam.smith I haven't tried CSL JSON yet since I'm unfamiliar with it, though CSL JSON will be an option. Would you like to post an answer that proposes how to use CSL JSON in this case? I'll upvote your answer if you do so. And would you mind telling me why bibtex does not work? I think I only uses `.bib` files and that I don't use any citation package (i.e. bibtex and biblatex) to process references. Then why does only CSL JSON, not `.bib` file, work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @adam.smith suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74255241/how-to-display-one-bibliography-in-different-styles-according-to-the-language-wh#comment131111291_74255241), using a CSL JSON (`.json`) file as a bibliography source does the trick:

1. Convert a `.bib` file to a CSL JSON (`.json`) file via pandoc by `pandoc .\tests.bib -t csljson -o tests.json` (see also [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268305/169454) in [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/));
2. Add `"lang-zh": "yes"` to the generated `.json` file (This process is mandatory since such a non-standard field as `lang-zh = {yes}` in `.bib` is not transferred to a CSL JSON);
3. Change the `bibliography` field in the YAML of `.md` file so that pandoc can refer to the `.json` file

[image]

## MWE

### `test.json`

```json
[
  {
    "URL": "http://yihui.name/knitr/",
    "author": [
      {
        "family": "Xie",
        "given": "Yihui"
      }
    ],
    "edition": "2nd",
    "id": "xie2015",
    "issued": {
      "date-parts": [
        [
          2015
        ]
      ]
    },
    "note": "ISBN 978-1498716963",
    "publisher": "Chapman; Hall/CRC",
    "publisher-place": "Boca Raton, Florida",
    "title": "Dynamic Documents with R and knitr",
    "type": "book"
  },
  {
    "author": [
      {
        "family": "陈骁"
      },
      {
        "family": "黄声华"
      },
      {
        "family": "万山明"
      },
      {
        "family": "庞珽"
      }
    ],
    "container-title": "电工技术学报",
    "id": "chen2012",
    "issue": "2",
    "issued": {
      "date-parts": [
        [
          2012
        ]
      ]
    },
    "page": "133-138",
    "title": "基于电无级变速器的内燃机最优控制策略及整车能量管理",
    "type": "article-journal",
    "volume": "27",
    "lang-zh": "yes"
  }
]
```

### `test.md`

```
---
bibliography: [test.bib]
csl: mod_apa_zh_pulipuli.csl
---

@xie2015

@chen2012
```